# C# object is type vs object as type

Tags: c#, types, casting, resharper

```
if(someVar is MyClass)
```

Resharper suggeted to replace this with

```
var some = someVar as MyClass;
if(some!= null){ /*.......*/ }
```

Is there any performance advantage? I remember something related with boxing and unboxing variables, but not sure, if I'm on the right path. Or is Resharper just suggesting proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it suggests this is probably because the former will require two casts:

```
if(someVar is MyClass) 
{
    var myVar = (MyClass) someVar;
}
```

The `is` operator does a cast behind the scenes and returns a boolean whether or not it is allowed.

If you use `as` though, you pretty much "cache" the result and you will only have one cast necessary.

```
var myVar = someVar as MyClass
if(myVar != null)
{
    // No cast needed
}
```